# Why I can't use i/10 in FOR LOOP, C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, sql-update

I can't use **i/10** in **FOR LOOP, C++.
Can you please find why I can't use that!!
when I write the code below;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum=0,i;
    cout<<"enter a no.";
    cin>>i;
    for(i;i!=0;i=i/10)
    {
        sum=sum+i%10;
    }
    cout<<"sum="<<sum;
}
```

After compiling it shows that:-

> cpp_2.cpp:8:7: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>
> for(i;i!=0;i=i/10)

Please help me!!

Comment: That warning is about the first mention of `i`. The loop can be written `for ( ; i != 0; i = i / 10)`. Or, more commonly, `for ( ; i != 0; i /= 10)`.

Comment: The warning is about `i` in `for(i;...)`, the first of the three parts. That's the one that has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can, although `i = i / 10` can be abbreviated to the arguably clearer `i /= 10`.

Your helpful compiler is warning you about the initialisation expression of the `for`, which is just `i`, and *that* is a no-op.

Writing

```
for (; i; i /= 10)
```

is equivalent, and will keep the compiler happy. Note that I've replaced the tautologous `i != 0` with, simply, `i`.